# theory behing open cv functions

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, disparity-mapping

I have used OpenCV library to for Stereo Camera Calibration and disparity map estimation. I used the tutorials available in OpenCV 3.3.1 documentation. For example, for disparity I have used the code from the following link:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html

It is working but I can't find detils of what is happenning in the functions used in the code such as left_matcher->computer or createdisparityWLSfilter. I want to read the theory behind these fucntion. So here I am looking for a good link or suggestion for that. I came across the following book:

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920044765.do

But I am not sure if this is the correct resource to read about details of opencv function. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The modules in `ximgproc` are part of the OpenCV contrib modules and not part of the standard OpenCV library; most of these functions have a lot of lacking documentation unfortunately. You might get a little more insight by taking a look at the pull requests on the contrib GitHub repo mentioning the `ximgproc` module: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+ximgproc. Of course there is the little bit of documentation on the functions, too: https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d17/group__ximgproc__filters.html#ga8a351f67b897bb7cdaccaef115bafcac

Comment: Also there are some references at the bottom of [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ximgproc/doc/edge_aware_filters.html#references) which contains papers relevant to the `ximgproc` module but not sure if any are related to the exact functions you're using. And similarly some refs at the bottom [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) which may be about stereo imaging.